A trick for derivatives of thermodynamic quantities
Starting from
$$dU=TdS-PdV$$
We can write, for instance $U(T,V)$ and $S(T,V)$ to obtain:
$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T dV=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V dT+T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_T dV-PdV$$
Identifying the terms in front of the differential forms we arrive at:
$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_VdT=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V$$
$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T =T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_T-P$$
This is the usual way I would go about deriving such equalities. What is about to follow is very unformal. I noticed that these expressions can be obtained much faster by dividing by, for instance $dT_V$, where the subscript indicates that $V$ is held constant. With this notation we have $\left(\frac{dU}{dT_V}\right)= \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V $
Then, we obtain the following immediately from the first equation:
$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V-P\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_V}_{=0}$$
and for the second equation we divide by $dV_T$:
$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T =T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_T-P\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial V}\right)_T}_{=1}$$
and we obtain the same results with this informal procedure.
My questions are: Does this work in general? Can the same be done for inexact differentials like $\delta Q$? Does this still work when the number of particles is varied, for instance when $U(N,V,P)$?

So you are assuming dV=0?

Not really, I am diving dV by another differential at a constant value of some parameter.

Is this an actual thermodynamics question or a math exercise?

It is not clear what is the mathematical meaning of $dT_V$ - it seems based on some intuitive considerations. The thermodynamic manipulations are just math with differentials - see here

I agree completely, yet this abuse of notation produces correct results here.

Is the question whether $(\delta Q/dT)_V$ has meaning?
